# entity framework mysql - error creating function

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a function in my mySQL database using entity framework migrations.  The SQL works great when I run it directly in MySQL Workbench but it fails when it runs in the EF migration.

How can I create a function using EF migration?

```
     Sql(@"
DROP function IF EXISTS `f_JumperName`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `f_JumperName` 
(
    JumperID int
)
RETURNS varchar(500)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(500);

    SELECT j.LastName + ', ' + j.FirstName
    INTO result
    FROM Jumper j
    WHERE j.JumperID = JumperID;

    RETURN x;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
");
```

Error message: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `f_JumperName` 
(...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the problem is caused by the `DELIMITER` sentences.

To work around it you can split your SQL in sentences, so you don't need to redefine the `;` delimiter. You get two separate sentences, one for the `drop` and one for the `create function`:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"DROP function IF EXISTS `f_JumperName`;");
    Sql(@"CREATE FUNCTION `f_JumperName` 
        (
            JumperID int
        )
        RETURNS varchar(500)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE result VARCHAR(500);
            SELECT j.LastName + ', ' + j.FirstName
            INTO result
            FROM Jumper j
            WHERE j.JumperID = JumperID;

            RETURN x;
        END;");
}
```

And you replace your previous `$$` characters with `;` at the end of the second sentence.

This is not fixing the real problem, which is not being able to set the delimiter correctly, but it works. I found some pages about really changing the delimiter through the `MySqlScript.Delimiter` property provided by the MySQL connector, but I don't know if it is a good practice (or even possible) to use it in a migration file, because you would have to access the real connection to the database somehow. I'm not really sure this can be used here.

Comment: Thank you very much Diana, that worked.  It would be nice if the same command that runs in mySQL Workbench worked in EF as well, but I'm happy to have a work around.

Comment: I was doubting this answer at first, but actually, it works great :) Works for `CREATE PROCEDURE` as well.